# Why CurrentUser implements HasHandlers in gwtp-sample-tab?

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp, event-bus

I am self learning GWT and GWTP. I am trying to set up my logging service and I want my currentUser object to be retrieved from the server before any Presenter that depends on it is revealed.

However, I have run into an issue which I think has to do with the fact that I don't understand why, on the gwtp-sample-tab example, the class [CurrentUser implements HasHandlers](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/blob/master/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-tab/src/main/java/com/gwtplatform/samples/tab/client/security/CurrentUser.java)!.

Can somebody explain it to me? Edit for a more precise question: what I would like to know is why, on the context of the sample, CurrentUser needs to implement HasHandlers. What functionality does that satisfy in the application?

Thanks a lot,
Manu

PS. I am new to StackOverflow so if you think something is wrong with my question, please let me know.

Comment: When ever you are  referring to something or some example  add link  to that, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [public class CurrentUser implements HasHandlers](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/blob/master/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-tab/src/main/java/com/gwtplatform/samples/tab/client/security/CurrentUser.java)

because to implement the method

```
@Override
    public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event) {
        eventBus.fireEvent(event);
    }
```

Which

> Fires the given event to the handlers listening to the event's type.

So When a new User object creates this event register and fires at Gatekeeper(`eventBus`).

Comment: I know what the interface does. What I do not understand is why, in the context of the sample, CurrentUser needs to implement that interface. It seems that it is not used anywhere since [AdminAreaPresenter](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/tree/master/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-tab/src/main/java/com/gwtplatform/samples/tab/client/application/adminarea) uses a Gatekeeper and the [Gatekeeper](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/blob/master/gwtp-samples/gwtp-sample-tab/src/main/java/com/gwtplatform/samples/tab/client/security/IsAdminGatekeeper.java) access the CurrentUser object directly

Comment: It makes sense. However I still don't see how GateKeeper listens to that particular event, there does not seem to be any handler registered for it. Is that due to some magic behind the curtains?

Comment: Haven't looked through full code, yes there must be something to recieve the event and handle it.

Comment: There is nothing on the sample code. Unless Gatekeeper has some magic to register handlers based on its attributes class name I think the event is not listened anywhere. Anyways thanks for the clarifications